# Тема магистерской диссертации

Tags: мобильная-разработка, android

Добрый вечер, подскажите тему для исследования. Направление мобильная разработка, желательно андроид.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Garf1eld](/users/18710/garf1eld)](/users/18710/garf1eld), магистерская диссертация, в отличие от бакалавров и специалитета, это самостоятельная **научноисследовательская** работа. Это должно быть оригинальное исследование, а постройка очередного ежедневника, который использует предоставленное API, как-то совсем не тянет под эти требования и на защите (а при хорошем руководителе на этапе выбора темы) может вызвать кучу вопросов.

Для выбора темы надо знать текущие малоизученные и актуальные вопросы в выбранной области и акцентировать исследование на них. К тому же выбор должен исходить как из личных предпочтений и знаний претендента, так и из паспорта заканчиваемой специальности. Именно поэтому важную роль играет руководитель, с которым надо вести обсуждение и если ему фиолетово, то менять его (ну или быть умным и упертым). Мой совет - посмотрите уже сделанные работы, посмотрите поднимающиеся постоянно вопросы и может что-то натолкнет на мысли. Очень актуальны темы анализа, базы знаний, вопросы проектирования сервисов.

Answer (score 0):

android wear + phone, сделайте связку, приложение-планировщик на телефоне (составляете расписание дня), а на часы приходят оповещения, вибро и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Различные протоколы, их производительность, использование различных типов взаимодействия в зависимости от условий, энергосбережение, безопасность.